# What's the differences between PHP versions from pkgs.org and remi

Tags: centos, php, centos7, yum, php7

I need to install PHP 7.3 on my CentOS 7.5 which already has PHP 5.4 and 7.0.27 versions but I saw difference in installing commands and since I'm not a professional I need to ask before begin installing it about the differences

In [virtualmin.com](https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/multiplephp) .. The commands to install PHP v7.0 **(Below)** .. Why I cannot replace 70 with 73 to install PHP v7.3? I google this line [rh-php73] and I found only v7.2 [rh-php72] in [centos.pkgs.org](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-testing-x86_64/rh-php72-php-mysqlnd-7.2.10-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) so Should I wait until the rh-php73 become a part of this website?

```
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install rh-php70 rh-php70-php-mysqlnd
```

Otherwise to install [PHP v7.3 (Remi)](https://www.virtualmin.com/node/48280) we should install [Epel, Remi] repositories then start to install PHP from remi

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum-config-manager --enable epel
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
```

I just need to understand what is Remi and is it safe to install PHP 7.3 on CentOS or should I wait until PHP v7.3 become a part of **centos.pkgs.org** website?

Comment: You should follow the directions given by virtualmin, and do not deviate from them. We cannot support virtualmin systems here.

Comment: The pkgs.org is merely an aggregator website for many package repositories (not just for CentOS).

Answer (score 0):

> Reformatted based on the comments below.

PHP is open source, so it makes possible that many maintainers can publish their repos and packages for the same thing.

`remi-*` are packed and managed by Remi Collet. We might consider that's a personal project, and when using it you accept all its limitation (on support side for instance).

`rh-*` carry the Red Hat prefix, and when you are a Red Hat customer they fall under the support contracts. Like Remi commented, there is no significant difference as `rh-*` are the upstream of `remi-*`.

Note that if you are not a Red Hat customer with support contracts, you should feel free to use whatever available.

Comment: Remi Collet manages _all_ of those packages; the Red Hat ones in his professional capacity, and the remi ones outside of work.

Comment: And FYI, SCL packages in remi repository are used as upstream for official RH collections (ex remi already have php73 which will be used to create rh-php73). Base packages are used as upstream for Fedora, which is used as upstream for RHEL base repostiory.